# Rails create and destroy nested attributes on update model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, nested

I have `Products` model which `has_many :tags`.

The tags are created on the product creation.

When I update a product, I can update all the attributes, including the tags' attributes.

But my question is, how can I, remove a tag or create another one when I update a product on my product update form?

Do I have to create a separate tag form or something like that?

Here is my update product form:

```
<%= form_for(@product), id: 'edit_form' do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :location %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>
      </div>
        <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= t.label "Hashtag" %>
          <%= t.text_field :name %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Update this item" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easy by using `gem 'nested_form'`. You can get the repository [`here`](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Answer (score 0):

and how do you add a tag with the same name to another product?

I think you have a wrong db schema for `taggings`, right now you are using `product_id` in the tag `table`, that means a `tag` will be available only for one `product`, but don't you want to sort your `products` by `tag` or `count` how many `products` were tagged by a specific `tag`, or may be search all `products` where `tag` is = zzz. etc..

you'll need `tag` model, `taggings` model and `product` model that you have already.

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :products, through: :taggings
```

**product.rb**

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

**taggings.rb**

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :product
```

with this relation you can in future do sort, search and count by tags..

full tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast
go with the "from scratch part"

**p.s.** removing a tag is not recommended as this tag might be used by another product. You can remove tags without any products later with a rake task.

Comment: 'and how do you add a tag with the same name to another product?'
My Tag model is working fine i guarantee you :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34539/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17971888-rails-create-and-destroy-nested-attri